# Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app (News Reader) that downloads and display PDF files from the web using CATiledLayer.
I am downloading each day news paper in PDF formate as requested by User.
Each day news paper contains 10 to 15 PDF files or pages.(one PDF per Page), each file up to 2 MB size.
i am creating CATiledLayer object for each file and assigning it to UIScrollview.

I am releasing CATiledLayer object with following code each time i request for new date news paper or PDF files.

```
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];
self.tiledLayer.contents=nil;
self.tiledLayer.delegate=nil;
[self.tiledLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocumentRef);
```

When i run application continues up to 10 to 15 mins, I get the following error:

Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

Can anyone help me out ?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue because of lack of memory available.Try running your app with instruments