# Random crashes in my client server application (Distributed Object)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have client server application using distributed object. some time my code is working fine but some times i am getting 
`*** NSDistantObject initWithCoder: 7 not given away for conn 0x100124c60` error. and some times my application receiving SIGARRT.

```
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
            sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
            Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saw it several times in iOS programming. It was always that I was running out of memory. for leaking or infinitive recursion.
see this: [Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843903/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable-will-re-try-after-a-continue) or [Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298772/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable-will-re-try-after-a-continue)

> "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'." means that something has gone so horribly wrong in your code that even the debugger bailed. As dragyn said, this usually involves some form of rapid object creation or recursion calling. Add a few NSLog lines into your code to help you see how far your code is getting and where it might be looping/calling itself.

from: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7314

Comment: When i am running my code from 'Instruments leaks', some times i am getting 'App quit unexpectedly'.

Comment: why i am getting *** NSDistantObject initWithCoder: 7 not given away for conn 0x100124c60 this error?

Comment: I don't know. You did something seriously wrong — so wrong, that even the debugger bails out. You will have to check each line of your code. most likely you have unbalance retain & release.

Comment: Sorry — there is not more I can do for you.